# How to prepare a string for JSON in Groovy or Java?

Tags: json, groovy

I have a string that needs to read from the database and sent as JSON. How can I make sure all quotes are escaped properly and handle any other characters that might make the String invalid JSON?

So for example I have the following code..

```
def jsonFormatted = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(products:finalList).toPrettyString()
```

And finalList variable is an array of HashMaps, where each Map has a key value pair, for example..

```
   "Product Id" -> "555"
   "Product Name" -> "32" Flat Screen TV"
```

Because that open quote in product name is not escaped, the program which reads the JSON on the other end breaks.

Any solution that uses JsonBuilder or JsonSlurper libraries would be optimal.

Comment: you don't worry about producing json. you produce a native data structure, and then encode it to json. the json library takes care of all the details for you. in other words, you've overthinking it.

Comment: @MarcB, I am not overthinking, this is an actual problem I am having, please see my example.

Comment: then your json library is broken, and you should be getting something else. a proper library outputs proper json, and doesn't spit out syntactically wrong json.

Comment: ToPrettyString() sounds like something human readable. You want something machine readable.

Comment: JsonBuilder would format the value escaped  as "Product Name": "32\" Flat Screen TV". Are you using JsonSlurper downstream on other end?

Comment: What you have should work. The problem you are reporting isn't the problem you have. Look elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only problem was I was calling toPrettyString() instead of toString() of JsonBuilder. Calling toString made JsonBuilder to escape that open quote. Special thanks to Gerd Castan for pointing this out.